# Disable Windows 10 Taskbar App Preview Hover Bring to Front

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

In Windows 10, I would like the taskbar thumbnail to appear, but I do not want that app to be brought to the front when I hover over that preview. Where is the setting to customize this?

Answer (score 0):

That setting is not adjustable. If you hover and wait, the app comes to the front and goes to the back when you stop hovering.

If you hover quickly (so just to see) it will not come to the front.

So how the Hovering works depends on exactly how and how fast you use it, it is not adjustable beyond that.

If you wish, you can turn Hovering off. I have learned to manage it.

[Turn off hovering](https://www.live2tech.com/how-to-disable-the-hover-display-for-desktop-icons-in-windows-10/#:%7E:text=%20How%20to%20Disable%20the%20Hover%20Display%20for,of%20the%20window%2C%20then%20click%20OK.%20More%20)

> The steps in this article were performed on a laptop computer in
> Windows 10. By completing the steps in this guide you will be stopping
> the behavior where you see a white window pop up over an icon when you
> hover above it.
>
> Step 1: Click the folder icon in the taskbar.
>
> Step 2: Select the File tab at the top-left of the window, then click
> the Change folder and search options button.
>
> Step 3: Click the View tab at the top of the window.
>
> Step 4: Scroll down and click the box to the left of Show pop-up
> description for folder and desktop items to remove the check mark.
>
> Step 5: Click the Apply button at the bottom of the window, then click
> OK.

Comment: Interesting that it is not adjustable. I have multiple windows machines, and the one I am setting up now is the only machine that does this.

Comment: That may be a function of setup and what was installed. My Insider machine and this Production system here work the very same way.

Answer (score 0):

In order to bring the application window to the front, the cursor has to go
over the preview and stay on it for some small amount of time.
A click on the preview will establish the window as the front.

As long as the cursor stays on the application entry on the taskbar,
but does not move over the image preview, the application's window will stay
where it is.

This is the only way to prevent the effect of displaying the full
application's window - to keep the cursor over the taskbar, not crossing
over to the preview image.